# Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity

```
 interface ERC20Interface {
     // function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external;
     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  returns (bool success);
     function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) 
     returns (bool success);
  }
 interface RegisterInterface {
    function isLogin(address _userAddr) public returns(bool);
 } 

contract RentBasic {
HouseState defaultState = HouseState.ReleaseRent;
struct HouseInfo {          
        uint8    landRate; 
        uint8    ratingIndex;  
        uint8    huxing;     
        string   houseAddress;      
        bytes32  houseId;   
        string   descibe;   
        string   landlordInfo;              
        string   hopeYou;       
        address  landlord;      
}
struct HouseReleaseInfo {
    HouseState    state;  
    uint32        tenancy;
    uint256       rent; 
    uint          releaseTime;  
    uint          updateTime; 
    uint          dealineTime;  
    bool          existed; 
}
// RentToken token;
ERC20Interface token;
TenancyAgreement tenancyContract;
RegisterInterface userRegister; 

modifier onlyLogin() {
    require(userRegister.isLogin(msg.sender));
    _;
}
function releaseHouse(string _houseAddr,uint8 _huxing,string _describe, string _info, uint32 _tenancy, uint256 _rent, string _hopeYou) public onlyLogin returns (bytes32) {
    uint256 nowTimes = now; 
    uint256 deadTime = nowTimes + 7 days;
    address houseOwer = msg.sender;
    // releaser should hold not less than 500 BLT
    // token.transferFrom(houseOwer, receiverPromiseMoney, promiseAmount);
    require(token.transferFrom(houseOwer, receiverPromiseMoney, promiseAmount),"Release_Balance is not enough");
    addrMoney[houseOwer] = promiseAmount;
    bytes32 houseIds = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(houseOwer, nowTimes, deadTime));
    hsInformation = HouseInfo({             
        landRate: 2     
    });
    houseInfos[houseIds] = hsInformation;
    hsReleaseInfos[houseIds] = HouseReleaseInfo({
        state: defaultState
    });
    // releations[houseId].leaser = houseOwer;
    ReleaseBasic(houseIds, 2, _houseAddr, _huxing, _describe, _info, _hopeYou, houseOwer);
    ReleaseInfo(houseIds, defaultState, _tenancy,_rent,nowTimes,deadTime,true);
    return houseIds;
}
```

}

It happend in the onlyLogin, Is there anyone know why?

Comment: Where are you implementing the interface? Where are you instantiating the `userRegister` variable?

Comment: It's another contrct

Comment: Well please add all the relevant code and how it interoperates